# Couldn't save backup of <filename> : git commit error during merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

I am trying to **merge** branch **p-jira-fix** changes into branch **p-main** changes. Branch **p-jira-fix** has renamed one file from **UserBase to EntityBase** and somehow when I am running the **git commit** command, I am facing the following error regarding that file :

Merge command I started with :

```
git checkout p-main
git pull origin p-jira-fix
```

```
cp: app/yyy/src/main/java/com/xxx/ces/domain/UserBase.java: No such file or directory
Couldn't save backup of app/yyy/src/main/java/com/xxx/ces/domain/UserBase.java
```

I could not find this exact error on sof or git related posts. Has anyone faced this OR resolved it?

Comment: This error message isn't a standard git error message (`git` wouldn't call the `cp` utility to copy files), it probably comes from an external script. Do you have any hooks installed on your local repository ? `ls .git/hooks`, files *not* ending with `.sample`.

Comment: Thanks, let me check that. I did feel the same but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @LeGEC - Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. It was actually a pre-commit hook which was not able to find that file and caused this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message isn't a standard git error message (`git` wouldn't call the `cp` utility to copy files), it probably comes from an external script.

One standard feature which makes `git` execute external scripts are hooks. Check if you have any hook activated on your local repository :
run `ls .git/hooks`, and check for files *not* ending with `.sample`.

Comment: It was actually a custom pre-commit hook which was not able to find that file and caused this issue. Found at  .git/hooks/pre-commit